# Retrieve all records from multiple tables using JDBC

Tags: join, jdbc, resultset

I need to get records from multiple tables. The scenario is as below:

```
Table A: columns{a1 (pk), a2, b1(fk)}
Table B: columns{b1 (pk), b2}
Table C: columns{b1 (pk),c2,c3,c4}
Table D: columns{d1 (pk)}
```

The resultSet should contain {a1,b1,c2,d1} for all results in A for a1. I used joins and it worked, but I would be working with something like 3 million records such that the join for 4 or 5 tables causes immense overhead. Is there any way around I make do this without the JOINs?

Comment: No, that is what joins are for.

Comment: You can de-normalize to reduce joins if possible at the cost of some redundancy in storage.